# Scroll through fixed element in scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering that is there any way to scroll through fixed element in scrollable content. Here is prepared fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbnfd8ts/13/

If I scroll on red box I should be able to scroll, but as you can see nothing happened. If I remove

`.scrollable-div{
  overflow-y:scroll;
....`

and leave default browser scroll it works. Of course I can pass mousewhell event throught fixed content, but I'm wondering about only css way. Anyone had this issue?

I'm not sure if it's not a browser bug

Comment: It seems your fiddle is doing what you want it to, unless I'm misunderstanding. When I place my cursor over the red div, I am able to scroll the parent container.

Comment: @JoelWorsham I am encoutering the error in Windows Chrome v67.0.3396.99 and Windows Firefox v52.8.1. What browser are you on?

Comment: I am using Chrome 67.0.3396.99 on Mac.